# pytorch indexing larger tensor with argmax of smaller tensor

Tags: indexing, pytorch

I have a tensor of shape: [2, 1024]
e.g.,

```
b = [[2.4, 3.2, 1.5, 6.9, ...],
     [5.9, 3.5, 1.2, 2.0, ...]]
```

and a tensor of shape [2, 1024, 10].
e.g.,

```
t = ...
```

I would like to index `t` using the argmax of `b` across the 0th dimension and produce a tensor `output` of dimension [1024, 10].
e.g. I would like

```
output[0,:] = t[1, 0, :]
output[1,:] = t[1, 1, :]
output[2,:] = t[0, 2, :]
output[3,:] = t[0, 3, :]
...
```

In other words, using `b` (its argmax) to choose whether to take the next row from sheet `[0]` or sheet `[1]` of `t`.

It is important that the order is unchanged with this indexing. If `b.max(0) = [a b c]` I cannot have the indices in the order `[b_ind, a_ind, c_ind]` or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to do the following:

```
output = t[b.argmax(0), torch.arange(t.shape[1]), :]
```